# Is there a finitely generated, algebraic $K$-algebra $A$ that is not a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

There is a well-known theorem that states that if $A$ is a finitely generated $K$-algebra, an integral domain and algebraic over $K$, then $A$ is a field. Is the integral domain condition necesary? I mean, is there an example of an algebraic algebra over $K$, such that is not a field? It may be kind of simple, but I'm a bit confused. Thank you.

Comment: I suppose that $K$ is a field: please add that in an edit. The integral domain condition is necessary but the condition that $A$ be finitely generated over $K$ is *not* necessary.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure. Consider $A=\mathbb R[x]/(x^2)$, which is generated by $\{1,x\}$ over $\mathbb R$ and is algebraic over $\mathbb R$ since $x^2=0$, yet is clearly not an integral domain hence not a field.

Comment: +1, yours is more general. Funny how often people here come up with the same counterexamples. Is it because they're natural, or because we've all been taught the same way?

Comment: Well, perhaps not *natural* in the strongest meaning of the word, but I feel that this is a minimal example in a certain sense.

Answer (score 7):

Another example is given by $K\times K$ (the product ring, thought of as a $K$-algebra via the diagonal embedding of $K$).  Any degree two example is either of this form, or of the form $K[x]/(x^2)$ considered in the other answers.

Comment: @BenjaLim: Dear Benjamin, It's finite-dimensional, hence algebraic, over $\mathbb R$.  (If you go through the proof that finite-dimensional implies algebraic, you can determine the actual minimal polynomials of the elements.)  Regards,

Answer (score 7):

After all these answers, this is not much more than a comment really. Being finitely generated by algebraic elements over $K$ implies (and is equivalent to) being finite dimensional as a vector space over $K$. And a commutative $K$ algebra that is finite dimesional is a field if and only if it is an integral domain, much in the same way as a finite commutative ring is a field if and only if it is an integral domain. In both cases the finiteness condition ensures that for the operation of multiplication by a fixed element injectivity implies surjectivity, in other words regular elements are invertible. And as the examples show there is no way you can take injectivity for granted: rings with zero divisors are very easy to construct.

I might add that if you drop the condition "integral domain", then your $K$-algebra need not even be commutatitive, and since (in English terminology) fields are supposed to be commutatitive, the quaternions would be another counterexample to your guess.

Answer (score 6):

For any field $K$, the algebra $A=K[x]/(x^2)$ is a finitely-generated $K$-algebra which is algebraic over $K$, but which is not an integral domain and certainly is not a field.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a large class of examples coming from a structure theorem. Suppose we restrict our attention to finite-dimensional commutative algebras over a field $k$ (these are automatically both finitely generated and algebraic). Such algebras are [Artinian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artinian_ring), and a structure theorem asserts that all Artinian rings are finite direct products of [Artinian local rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artinian_ring). Examples which are finite-dimensional commutative over $k$ include finite direct products of the rings of the form $k[x]/x^n$, or more generally $K[x]/x^n$ where $K$ is a finite extension of $k$.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the assumption that $\mathcal A$ is a finitely generated $K$-algebra.

Let $\mathcal A$ be a $K$-algebra that is algebraic over $K$ and an integral domain. Let $a$ be a non-zero element of $\mathcal A$. Since $\mathcal A$ is algebraic, there exists a polynomial $f(x)\in K[x]$ such that $f(a)=0$. Define a homomorphism $$\phi: K[x]\rightarrow K[a]\\g(x)\mapsto g(a)$$ The map is surjective and $(f(x))\subseteq \ker(\phi)\subseteq K[x]$. We have $$K[x]/\ker(\phi)\cong K[a]$$

$K[x]$ is a PID, and $K[a]$ is an integral domain so $\ker(\phi)$ is a maximal ideal. It follows that $a$ is invertible, so $\mathcal A$ is a field.

---

For completeness:

- $\Bbb Q[x]/(x^2)$ is an algebraic $\Bbb Q$-algebra that is neither a integral domain, nor a field. Any element in $\Bbb Q[x]/(x^2)$ may be written $a+bx$, and is a root of the polynomial $y^2-2ay+a^2$.
- $\Bbb R[x]$ is a $\Bbb Z[x]$-algebra that is an integral domain, but neither algebraic nor a field. (I'm not sure if there is a counter-example when $\mathcal A$ is a finitely generated $K$-algebra)

Comment: Why would $\phi$ be surjective? That would imply $\mathcal{A}$ can be generated by a single element, which certainly isn't the case in general, even if $\mathcal{A}$ is a field.

Comment: @Thorgott Thank you! Fixed.